# Angular 9 application freezes after processing MQTT messages for 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, mqtt, angular9

My application is based on Angular 9 framework. It has a feature that visualizes live data using ngx-charts published from MQTT(ngx-mqtt). I am using Angular Material 9 matTable to show the records and the values in the column change continuously until you close the application or unsubscribe the MQTT live data. The Application is coping it up well until 5 minutes and later on, it just freezes and the page becomes unresponsive.

How can I handle this issue without affecting other functionalities in the application? Suggestion/guidance to address this issue is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance!!!.

**component.ts**

```js
//Initializing ngx-charts
constructor() {
    this.multi = [{
            name: 'label1',
            series: new Array(),
        },
        {
            name: 'label2',
            series: new Array(),
        },
    ];

}
ngOnInit() {
    this.initChart();
    this.subscribingToMQTT();
}
initChart() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this.multi[0].series.push({
            name: 0,
            value: 0,
        });

        this.multi[1].series.push({
            name: 0,
            value: 0,
        });
    }
}
subscribingToMQTT() {
    this._mqttSubscriber = this.mqttService
        .observe(`myTopic`)
        .subscribe(
            (jsonLiveData: IMqttMessage) => {
                let _data = jsonLiveData.payload.toString();
                console.log('Live Data: ', _data);
                this.JSONLiveData = this.IsJsonString(`[${_data}]`);
                this.bindTxRxData(this.JSONLiveData[0]);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Something went wrong while fetching live data from MQTT');
            }
        );
}
bindTxRxData(data) {
    if (data) {
        this.bindView(moment().seconds(), data);
    }
}

bindView(currentSecond: number, data) {
    if (currentSecond <= 12) {
        this.multi[0].series[0].name = 5;
        this.multi[0].series[0].value += data.rx;
        this.multi[1].series[0].name = 5;
        this.multi[1].series[0].value += data.tx;
    } else if (currentSecond > 12 && currentSecond <= 24) {
        this.multi[0].series[1].name = 10;
        this.multi[0].series[1].value += data.rx;
        this.multi[1].series[1].name = 10;
        this.multi[1].series[1].value += data.tx;
    } else if (currentSecond > 24 && currentSecond <= 36) {
        this.multi[0].series[2].name = 15;
        this.multi[0].series[2].value += data.rx;
        this.multi[1].series[2].name = 15;
        this.multi[1].series[2].value += data.tx;
    } else if (currentSecond > 36 && currentSecond <= 48) {
        this.multi[0].series[3].name = 20;
        this.multi[0].series[3].value += data.rx;
        this.multi[1].series[3].name = 20;
        this.multi[1].series[3].value += data.tx;
    } else if (currentSecond > 48 && currentSecond <= 60) {
        this.multi[0].series[4].name = 25;
        this.multi[0].series[4].value += data.rx;
        this.multi[1].series[4].name = 25;
        this.multi[1].series[4].value += data.tx;
    }
    if (this.multi[0].series.length > 50 && this.multi[1].series.length > 50) {
        this.multi[0].series.splice(0, 20);
        this.multi[1].series.splice(0, 20);
        this.multi = [...this.multi];
    } else {
        this.multi = [...this.multi];
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
        this._mqttSubscriber.unsubscribe();
    }
```

**Component.html**

```html
<ngx-charts-line-chart [scheme]="colorScheme" [legend]="legend"[results]="multi"
   [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend"
   [legendTitle]="title" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
   [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
   [autoScale]="autoScale" [animations]="animations">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

Comment: Please share some code. We can't help you without providing a simple reproducible example.

Comment: Please add further information (e.g. a sample message, how frequently are messages being received, what have you tried). It looks like some code is missing that may be relevant (currently I don't see how `this.multi[0].series.length` can get over 5 as the only time you add elements is in `initChart()`) so perhaps simplify your code (ideally provide a working sample on one of the angular playgrounds using an observable that simulates the incoming messages).